# What do the braces () in URL regular expression represent?

Tags: regex

For example, in

```
r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'
```

I understand all regexes except (\d{4}). Four digits but why the braces?

(python/django example)

another example:

```
r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'
```

Comment: They are used to create captured groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Braces are used for grouping, which can be used to extract a subset of a match. They can also be used to indicate that a subset repeats (or is optional), although your regex does not use them that way.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Based on the usage, I'd wager that the code matching this URL is using the brackets to extract the year so that it can be used in a query. See the group function of the [Match object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects)

---

Django automatically extracts grouped subexpressions and uses them as parameters for your view:

> The view gets passed an HttpRequest as its first argument and any values captured in the regex as remaining arguments.
>   ...
>   A request to `/articles/2005/03/` would match the third entry in the list. Django would call the function `news.views.month_archive(request, '2005', '03')`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Comment: very helpful indeed. i guess the braces in this specific case group anything before the / - forward slashes of the url and each group obviously represent a directory. i still dont understand why we can do just this r'^articles//\d{4}//$ instead of r'^articles/(\d{4})/$

Comment: @masterpiece - If you aren't extracting the year, then they are equally useful. If you are extracting the year, then grouping those four digits makes it easier to extract them (rather then having to parse them out in a second step). If I remember correctly, Django automatically extracts grouped subexpressions and uses them as parameters for your view, but it's been several years.

Comment: thx a lot. django also uses named groups - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#named-groups for anyone else interested.

Answer (score 2):

Besides grouping part of a regular expression together, round brackets also create a "backreference". A [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) stores the part of the string matched by the part of the regular expression inside the parentheses.